# Imputing Missing Values based on Geo-Spatial and Temporal Data Points

Tags: r, imputation

I have the following data frame.

```
data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Item = c("A","A", "B", "B","C"),
                       CITY = c("C1",
                                "C2","C3","C4", "C5"),
                        lat = c(23.1608938,
                                23.1608938,13.0836939,23,23.0216238),
                       long = c(79.9497702,
                                79.9497702,80.270186,74,72.5797068),
                      DATE = c("2019-04-12","2019-05-03","2019-06-28","2019-10-18",
                              "2019-12-23"),
                   BASIC_RATE = c(5445, 5445, 13380, 15000, 15000),
                   MIN_RATE = c(5150, 5150, NA, 5150, 5150),
                   MAX_RATE = c(5500, 5500, NA, 5500, 5500),
                     Region = as.factor(c("R1 ","R1 ", "R2 ","R3 ","R3 ")))
```

My objective is to impute the missing values in Min and Max Rates based on geo-spatial (latitude and longitude) and temporal data (Date) grouped by Region.

Any recommended approach for imputing the missing values for the above case.

Comment: I am not fully sure to understand what you want to do. For your example data, the case is even worse as the NAs appear for Region R2 which is a single entry. Thus, any grouped imputation has no "neighbours" in the region. Obvious imputation candidates are group medians, etc. However, how this applies to a temporal or geo-spatial case would need to be reviewed. If your DATEs have no specific order/interval per group, it is not trivial to judge on a good imputation measure. The same applies for the lat/lon positions, unless you can nail down a center or most frequent places. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Ray. This is a representative sample data from my larger dataset (~500k). I just wanted to know which are the approaches that can be used to impute data for such a sample dataset. As per my understanding, a distance matrix and coefficient of variance for rates can be derived to find nearby neighbors which can then be used for imputation.  In this approach, I wasn't considering the date. I was hoping to find out other approaches that takes all the data points into consideration for imputation.

Hope it clarifies my question.

Comment: @Mayanak I guess you answered your question then. Similar to the "closeness" in terms of distance, you can address the temporal aspect on a similar basis. The assumption here would be that close neighbours show similar rate behaviour when the time difference it not "too big". Obviously, this assumes that your DATEs "matter" and influence the rates based on the lat/lon. I guess you can show this with the complete datasets.